# How to Call a KeyEventArgs Methods in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

Inside the listbox,if double click the listbox items, the values of the listbox items assign to the dynamic textbox within the listbox.(I created a dynamictextbox withint the listbox).Then I need to modify the textbox values.After that click enter key, the textbox values Added to the listbox items then dynamictextbox removed.when click the esc key the initial values added to listbox item.

I have problem in inside the MouseEventArg method how can call the keyeventArgs method.

C#

```
  System.Windows.Controls.TextBox dynamicTextBox = new System.Windows.Controls.TextBox();

    string previousvalue;

    private void items_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //Get the index value
        var index = lstbxindex.Items.IndexOf(lstbxindex.SelectedItem);


        //set the textbox height and width property 
        dynamicTextBox.Width = 230;
        dynamicTextBox.Height = 50;

        //Add a textbox to the listbox 
        this.lstbxindex.Items.Add(dynamicTextBox);

        //To assign the selectedITem values to textbox
        dynamicTextBox.Text = lstbxindex.SelectedItem.ToString();

        //Get the textbox values before editing
        previousvalue = dynamicTextBox.Text;

        //Remove the values from the listbox item
        lstbxindex.Items.RemoveAt(index);


        dynamicTextBox.AcceptsReturn = true;

    }




private void checkenterclicked(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            EnterClicked(sender, e);
            //dynamicTextBox.PreviewKeyDown += EnterClicked;
        }
    }

    private void EnterClicked(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            using (DatabaseConnector databaseConnection = new DatabaseConnector(ApplicationConstants.ConnectionString))
            using (ProjectsTable projectsTable = new ProjectsTable(databaseConnection))
            {


                //Here Filter the Name from project Table which DbActive state is zero
                projectsTable.AddFilter(new Filter<ProjectsColumnTypes>(ProjectsColumnTypes.DbActive, CompareOperator.Equals, true));
                projectsTable.Read();

                projectsTable.AddFilter(new Filter<ProjectsColumnTypes>(ProjectsColumnTypes.Name, CompareOperator.Equals, dynamicTextBox.Text));

                projectsTable.Read();

                foreach (DtoProjectsRow row in projectsTable.Rows)
                {
                    //Guid DbId = row.DbId;
                    Guid DbId = row.DbId;

                    var UpdateRow = projectsTable.NewRow();


                    UpdateRow.Name = dynamicTextBox.Text;

                    UpdateRow.DbId = DbId;


                    UpdateRow.DbActive = true;

                    // Alter the row to the table.
                    projectsTable.AlterRow(UpdateRow);

                    // Write the new row to the database.
                    projectsTable.Post();

                    //Add the items in comboBox
                    lstbxindex.Items.Add(dynamicTextBox.Text);
                }
                // dynamicTextBox = e.Source as System.Windows.Controls.TextBox;

            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
            {
                lstbxindex.Items.Add(previousvalue);
                lstbxindex.Items.Remove(dynamicTextBox);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

Subscribe to your dynamic textbox keyevent. Put that in the constructor. For example :

```
System.Windows.Controls.TextBox dynamicTextBox = new System.Windows.Controls.TextBox();

string previousvalue;

    public MainWindows()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //subscribe to previewKeyDown, KeyDown will not work for enter key
        dynamicTextBox.PreviewKeyDown += dynamicTextBox_KeyDown;
    }

    // this will hit if any key is pressed
    void dynamicTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
             using (DatabaseConnector databaseConnection = new DatabaseConnector(ApplicationConstants.ConnectionString))
             using (ProjectsTable projectsTable = new ProjectsTable(databaseConnection))
            {


            //Here Filter the Name from project Table which DbActive state is zero
            projectsTable.AddFilter(new Filter<ProjectsColumnTypes>(ProjectsColumnTypes.DbActive, CompareOperator.Equals, true));
            projectsTable.Read();

            projectsTable.AddFilter(new Filter<ProjectsColumnTypes>(ProjectsColumnTypes.Name, CompareOperator.Equals, dynamicTextBox.Text));

            projectsTable.Read();

            foreach (DtoProjectsRow row in projectsTable.Rows)
            {
                //Guid DbId = row.DbId;
                Guid DbId = row.DbId;

                var UpdateRow = projectsTable.NewRow();


                UpdateRow.Name = dynamicTextBox.Text;

                UpdateRow.DbId = DbId;


                UpdateRow.DbActive = true;

                // Alter the row to the table.
                projectsTable.AlterRow(UpdateRow);

                // Write the new row to the database.
                projectsTable.Post();

                //Add the items in comboBox
                lstbxindex.Items.Add(dynamicTextBox.Text);
            }
            // dynamicTextBox = e.Source as System.Windows.Controls.TextBox;

        }
    }

private void items_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    //Get the index value
    var index = lstbxindex.Items.IndexOf(lstbxindex.SelectedItem);


    //set the textbox height and width property 
    dynamicTextBox.Width = 230;
    dynamicTextBox.Height = 50;

    //Add a textbox to the listbox 
    this.lstbxindex.Items.Add(dynamicTextBox);

    //To assign the selectedITem values to textbox
    dynamicTextBox.Text = lstbxindex.SelectedItem.ToString();

    //Get the textbox values before editing
    previousvalue = dynamicTextBox.Text;

    //Remove the values from the listbox item
    lstbxindex.Items.RemoveAt(index);


    dynamicTextBox.AcceptsReturn = true;

}
```

Comment: I want to edit some values to the textbox. this will hit if any key is pressed

Comment: @LogeswariJegatheesan yes but it will ignore other type of key because it only filter for enter key. give it a try without debugging or just debug at : using (DatabaseConnector databaseConnection = new DatabaseConnector(ApplicationConstants.ConnectionString))

Comment: You are welcome. Please vote or mark as answer if this is really helpful . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just do

```
System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs ee = new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs();
ee.KeyCode = Keys.Enter;
EnterClicked(sender,ee);
```